# Find n-th element of Fibonacci sequence given first two integers

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some practicing and I've come across a question that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.

You are given the first two integers of a Fibonacci sequence. You are to then find the n-th element of the sequence.

For example, given the sequence `2,4`, output the `4th` element. The answer is `10`, because:

`2,4,6,10`

How would I program this solution in JavaScript (with and without recursion)?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that Stack Overflow is a place to get specific answers to your programming questions, not a code-writing service. Please make an effort to solve the problem yourself, and come back once you have some code and a specific question. Consider reviewing the helpful article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Without recursion:

```
function Fibonacci(first, second, n){
      let iter = 3; //set it to 3 since you are passing the first and second

      //Use while loop instead of recursive calls to Fibonacci
      while(iter < n){
           let temp = first;
           first = second;
           second = temp + first;
           iter++;
      }

      //If n is one, return first
      if(n == 1)
         return first;

      //Display last item in sequence
      console.log(second);

       //Or return it
      return second;
}
```

With Recursion:

```
 function Fibonacci(first, second, n){
      //If n - 2 (passing first 2 in sequence) is greater than or equal to 0, do operations and recall Fibonacci
      if((n - 2) > 0){
          let temp = first;
          first = second;
          second = temp + first;
          n--;
          return Fibonacci(first, second, n);
      }

      //If n is one, return first
      if(n == 1)
         return first;

      //Display last item in sequence
      console.log(second);

      //Or return it
      return second;
}
```

Comment: The recursive version doesn't work. It returns `6` for `Fibonacci(2,4,4)`, `(2,4,5)`, `(2,4,6)` and so on, but it should return `10`, `16`, and `26` for those. Both versions return the wrong value for `n = 1` (they should return `first`  instead of `second` in that case).

Comment: @Paulpro You are wrong. The recursive does return 10 for Fibonacci(2, 4, 4), and 16 for (2, 4, 5). I just tested it to make sure.

Comment: It logs it at some point, but it doesn't return it. Remove the 'console.log` inside the function and run `console.log( Fibonacci(2,4,5) );` and you'll see what I mean. I think you can fix it just by putting `return` in front of the inner recursive call.

Comment: @Paulpro Good call, i forgot to do a return statement, that's what I get for writing this in C# and trying to translate it over to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using recursion:

```js
function nthFib( u0, u1, n ) {
    return n > 1 ? nthFib( u1, u0 + u1, n - 1 ) : u0;
}

console.log( nthFib( 2, 4, 4 ) );
```

Here is one using a loop:

```js
function nthFib( u0, u1, n ) {
    for ( let i = 2; i <= n; i++ )
        [ u0, u1 ] = [ u1, u0 + u1 ];
    return u0;
}

console.log( nthFib( 2, 4, 4 ) );
```

You can also do it using [a closed formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) and then you don't need recursion or looping:

```js
function nthFib( u0, u1, n ) {
    const sqrt5 = 5**.5;
    const golden = (1 + sqrt5)/2;
    const a = (u1 - u0*(1 - golden))/sqrt5;
    const b = (u0*golden - u1)/sqrt5;
    return Math.round(a*golden**--n + b*(1 - golden)**n);
}

console.log( nthFib( 2, 4, 4 ) );
```